# Get SQL Server schema via a SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I've inherited a clunky and horribly un-documented site from a bad developer and am trying to get a look at the database schema. Unfortunately the web host is the worst I've ever dealt with and has no control panel capability for viewing the db schema or even exporting tables.

Is there any way that I can get a look at the schema via a SQL query (this would be with ASP + SQL Server)? My end goal here is to see what tables exist, possibly get a SQL dump of the vital tables, and then recreate the whole thing the right way.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` schema is a good place to start:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
```

...and so on.

You might also want to have a look at using [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx), an API to get at the metadata in SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you, this is precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` is very useful. It provides details of the columns along with table name.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if simple queries like

```
SHOW TABLES;
DESCRIBE table_name;
SHOW TABLE STATUS from table_name;
```

are valid in MS SQL. They would also be useful

Comment: They're not :) There are a few other ways, like `SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type='U'` and so on, but no `SHOW TABLES` in MS SQL, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

SchemaSpy http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/ is a great tool for analyzing existing databases. It generates html lists of table and constraints as well as a graphical representation of relationships