# SQL SERVER: Issues with TSQL to check if schema on database exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

On SQL SERVER:

I have a schema on my database created using command:

```
CREATE SCHEMA my-schema AUTHORIZATION [G_USER]
```

When I try search for the schema using the following statement I do not get any result.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name=N'my-schema'
```

However when I try
`SELECT * FROM sys.schemas` 
I get a whole bunch of other schemas but not the my-schema which I created on the database.

Am I doing something wrong? Any Help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317398/get-sql-server-schema-via-a-sql-query

Comment: Are you sure you created it? The statement should fail with a syntax error unless you use brackets around `my-schema`.

Comment: Is that the exact query you were using to create the schema?, if not, please show us the right one.

Comment: EXEC('CREATE SCHEMA [my-schema] AUTHORIZATION [G_USER]')

Comment: the schema can be seen under my-database/security/schemas/my-schema/ when I click down in MSSMS

Comment: `sys.schemas` lists schemas from current database. Try `use [my-database]; select * from sys.schemas;`.

Comment: How about select * from [my-database].sys.schemas WHERE name='my-schema'; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my syntax (from the personal code-snipplets vault)

```
if not exists(select 1 from information_schema.schemata where schema_name='my-schema')
BEGIN
    print 'Creating the schema : [my-schema]' 
    EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA [my-schema] AUTHORIZATION dbo;')
END


if exists(select 1 from information_schema.schemata where schema_name='my-schema')
BEGIN
print 'Schema Exists : [my-schema]' 
END
```

(My personal code below, just in case)

```
if not exists(select 1 from information_schema.schemata where schema_name='LookupSchema')
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA LookupSchema AUTHORIZATION dbo;')
END

GO
```